# Postgresql: How to use curl with function

Tags: postgresql, curl, plpgsql, npgsql

I have a function `parse_sdf(text)`.
When I call the function like this:

```
INSERT INTO test.table("Id", "Test") 
(SELECT props -> 'Id', props -> 'Test' FROM parse_sdf());
```

When I execute the `INSERT` with `pgsql` I want to pass as a parameter a text file which I download via `curl`.
Like this:

```
INSERT INTO test.table("Id", "Test") 
(SELECT props -> 'Id', props -> 'Test' FROM parse_sdf('curl http://test/Files/text.txt'));
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**

Postgres version: 10
Command will be executed with ExecuteSqlCommand command from Npgsql package for EF Core.

Comment: [Execute system commands in postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128229/execute-system-commands-in-postgresql#128254)

Comment: I know the COPY ... PROGRAM command. But this doesn't help me in my case.

Comment: There is pl/sh language for PostgreSQL - https://github.com/petere/plsh - allows you to run linux shell scripts inside PostgreSQL. Did you try it? We use it for similar "corner cases"...

Comment: I use npgsql for EF Core. So I need a pl/pgsql command.

Comment: Why does  `COPY FROM PROGRAM` not help you? You example URL indicates a local file? is that the case? Please clarify your question and always disclose your version of Postgres. In this case also your OS and relevant client / server setup.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Unless there is a way to combine a function and the curl command with the COPY FROM PROGRAM. File is not local all the time.

Comment: Start by showing your function definition.

Comment: It is a third party function. It accepts a text value which it splits and parses.