# Error: Unable to call postgres function in CURL GET request

Tags: postgresql, curl, postgis, postgrest

I have a custom function in my remote PostgreSQL/PostGIS database that finds the nearest linestring based on the given coordinates (lon, lat in CRS: 4326). I am on Windows 10 (x64 machine) and using PostgREST API to make my curl request talk to the remote pg database.

The curl command is:

```
curl "http://my_host:my_port/my_table?select=get_nearest_linestring(9.18233279,45.47184631)"
```

I get the error:

```
{"hint":null,"details":null,"code":"42703","message":"column my_table.get_nearest_linestring does not exist"}
```

I could see a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004712/postgresql-how-to-use-curl-with-function) but I don't get any hints. Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not a postgrest expert, but I think this is what you're looking for: https://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/api.html?highlight=stored%20procedure#s-procs

Comment: What are the parameters of `get_nearest_linestring`, can you share the function signature?